# Local travel to Gare de Rennes, France, by 6.17 am

Tags: transit, trains, france, taxis

I have TGV train from Gare de Rennes city to CDG airport at 6.17 am morning.
I have to get to Gare de Rennes from Centre de la Hublias in time to catch the train at 6.17 am.

Can I arrive easily or it will make me problem?

Can you suggest some way that makes the morning short journey easy to catch the train at gare de rennes in time at 6.17 am?

Comment: What day of the week is that? There are public transit options that early on weekdays but not week-ends, apparently.

Comment: Also, I suppose you mean Centre de la Hublais (near the Supelec Campus, in Cesson-Sévigné), not Hublias?

Comment: @jcaron, Thanks. It is saturday morning. The address is "Centre La Hublais", avenue de la Hublais, 35510 Cesson sévigné

website :www.hublais.fr

Comment: On Saturday morning, starting in September, there's a bus you can take, but it is quite a distance away (Google Maps says 21 minutes walk, and I find Google Maps to be usually quite optimistic on walk times), with a not-so-straightforward itinerary to get you there. And the schedule is not a very good match. A taxi probably remains the best option.

Comment: @jcaron, thanks. Can you say/guess the approximate fare of taxi on this 2 km distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Centre de la Hublias appears to be 6 km from the Gare de Rennes.

Take a taxi. You could arrange the taxi pick-up the day before by speaking to a taxi driver, or calling a taxi company on your mobile.